# Groups not showing up in the users.aspx page

Tags: 2013, permissions, groups

When I goto my sharepoint 2013 **site collection** -> **Site settings** -> **Site Permissions**

the browser opens with `siteurl/_layouts/15/user.aspx`

I only see two groups in that page.

When I goto `siteurl/_layouts/15/groups.aspx`  , I see all the groups which are present. I can also see all the site permission groups in designer. Anyidea on how to fixed the `users.aspx` to show all groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site permissions shows which groups have been granted access.
groups.aspx shows what groups have been created and are available to use.

When you create a group you don't have to use it for permissions.  I have created groups that are only used in workflow. Or are used only for one library.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a SP to check if it is so, but I think that

- `siteurl/_layouts/15/user.aspx` lists the user permission groups for the **site** (i.e. those permissions are valid on the current site), whereas
- `siteurl/_layouts/15/groups.aspx` lists the user permission groups of the **site collection** (i.e. these are the permission groups that have been created inside the site collection, but it doesn't mean the groups have any permissions added)

This is by design and intended to be so.

Comment: This is almost correct.  siteurl/_layouts/15/groups.aspx doesn't have any permissions assignment or relevance.  It is simply a list of groups that have been created in the site collection (good point of clarity).

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of `siteurl/_layouts/15/groups.aspx`  denote to People and group of your site so you can see all groups which are present

At `siteurl/_layouts/15/user.aspx` denote to `Site Permissions Settings` so you may be you `stopped inheriting permission` , and use custom permission .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Groups don’t show in user.aspx page, which means those groups don’t have permissions in this site. You need to grant permissions to those groups manually. - coutesy Dean Wng